# Modal não sobe ao ser chamado pela jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal

Depois de alguns erros, consegui fazer a jquery funcionar. Agora eu preciso chamar o Modal de dentro da jquery no change de uma DropdownList. Abaixo minha jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#faturarParaDrop').change(function() {
        var $div = $('#modalPartial'); //exibir a modal
        var idcustomer = $(this).val(); //valor do id da dropdownlist
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDados/")' + idcustomer,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(dados) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(dados));
                var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dados));
                alert(obj.Nome); ?
                ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? //Como chamo aqui?
            },
            error: function(erro) {}
        })
    });
});
```

Na minha View, tenho a View e o Modal que devará ser exibido, veja a View abaixo com o Modal

```
<div class="section-page" ng-controller="EditarMarkupCtrl"></div>

<h2>Editar Fatura Para</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

        <div id="modal">
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Markup!!!</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>O Markup para o Cliente... é zero(0).</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderId)
        <div class="topo-detalhe-assinatura-pedidos">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Pedido:</label>
                    @ViewBag.Order.OrderId
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Forma de pagamento:</label>
                    @ViewBag.Order.PaymentMethodSystemName
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Status:</label>
                    @ViewBag.Order.Status
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Pedido criado em:</label>
                    @ViewBag.Order.CreatedOn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Faturar para:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Options, "CustomerId", "Description", Model.CustomerId), new { @id = "faturarParaDrop" })
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "GetOrderDetail", "SearchOrders", new { id = Model.OrderId }, new { @class = "btn btn-cinza wd-170" })
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-verde wd-270 f-right" value="Salvar" onclick="startLoading();" />
        }

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
```

Se eu coloco um botão como esse e chamo o Modal, ok, funciona

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

A pergunta é: Como eu faço para chamar a partir da jquery? Não posso chamar pelo botão, mas sim, pelo change da DropDownList.

Comment: Sua partialView com a modal está completa? Ou você que cortou uma parte dela? content.js é arquivo seu de javascript? Debugou no console pra tentar entender onde exatamente está o problema?

Comment: Vamos por parte, cria uma função para chamar o modal, verifica se está certo e aparecendo o modal. Se tiver chamando certo, chama essa função no change do dropdown para verificar se funciona e atende seu problema.

Comment: Então, estava chamando pelo botão. Esse exemplo eu peguei na W3Schools, mas passar para o change que é que não tô sabendo fazer

Comment: Com esse código, consigo chamar o moda ` <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>`

Comment: Se coloco a chamada no botão salvar, ele exibe mas continua sem que eu feche o modal. Como faria para fechar o modal e só continuar após o modal ser fechado?

Comment: Colocando isso no sucesso da jquery eu chamo o modal: `$("#myBtnModal").click();`, mas acho isso gambi

Answer (score 1):

No seu HTML não encontrei nenhum elemento com id modalPartial. Mas de acordo com o seu exemplo, isso deve funcionar para exibir o modal dentro da jquery no change:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Caso queira fechar o modal em algum momento depois, use:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Breno, da forma acima não rola. Parece que o modal é chamado, mas não é mostrado e tenho que sair, pois não consigo acessar nada na tela devido ao modal, mas ele não é mostrado